# Fragment loses reference to activity without reason

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-context

In a fragment of mine I sometimes have an exception stating that my `Context` is null.

I, for now, can't recreate the issue, as I tried to access the crashing code in many different ways without consistent results.

Here is the crash log I get :

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: eu.side.aurora, PID: 12940
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference
        at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:101)
        at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:258)
        at eu.side.aurora.views.fragments.StepStock.lambda$onCreateView$2$StepStock(StepStock.java:161)
```

And the code if references

```
    InterventionsViewModel interventionsViewmodel = ViewmodelProviders.of(getActivity()).get(InterventionsViewModel)
    interventionsViewmodel.getExceptions().observe(getActivity(), exception ->{
        if(exception instanceof QuantityOverflowException){
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No you just can't add more stock than there is available!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        if(exception instanceof ScannedArticleNotFoundException){
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "This article doesn't even exist! Get your shit together please!²", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
     });
```

The weird thing is that I reference getActivty() pretty much everywhere in my fragment's `onCreateView` and it crashes nowhere but there.

To access the code with the view below I just press the **+** or **-** buttons to add or remove articles from my list. When it reaches the max it sends a `Toast` in order to notify the user.

[image: Screen that causes the crash]

When the **plus** or **minus** buttons are clicked they notify the `ViewModel`, which will change the observable object I observe before.

Does anyone know where does this come from? I assume it comes from my fragment detaching from my `Activity` but I can't figure out how it can do this as I never touch my fragment again after creating it.

Thanks in advance,
Matthieu

Edit : As requested, here is the full fragment's code
    package eu.side.aurora.views.fragments;

```
public class StepStock extends Fragment {
    private INextStep nextStep;

    @BindView(R.id.articles_autocomplete)
    AutoCompleteTextView articlesAutocomplete;
    @BindView(R.id.articles_recycler)
    RecyclerView articleRecycler;


    private AccountManager accountManager;
    private Account account;
    private ArrayList<DetailedArticle> articles;
    private ArrayList<Article> stockedArticles;
    private StockRecyclerAdapter stockAdapter;
    private InterventionsViewModel interventionViewModel;

    public StepStock() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @return A new instance of fragment StepStock.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static StepStock newInstance() {
        return new StepStock();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_step_stock, container, false);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, view);

        interventionViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(getActivity()).get(InterventionsViewModel.class);

        /* UI Intialization */
        articleRecycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));


        /**
         * Stock recycler view
         * Used to keep track of stock used in an intervention
         * OnPlus -> Add one from article
         * OnMinus -> Remove one from article
         * */
        stockedArticles = new ArrayList<>();
        stockAdapter = new StockRecyclerAdapter(stockedArticles, new StockRecyclerAdapter.OnArticleClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onArticleClicked(int position) {
                //new intent
            }

            @Override
            public void onPlusClicked(int position) {
                interventionViewModel.addOneToStockAtArticle(stockAdapter.getData().get(position));
            }

            @Override
            public void onMinusClicked(int position) {
                interventionViewModel.minusOneOrRemoveAtArticle(stockAdapter.getData().get(position));
            }
        });

        interventionViewModel.getCurrentIntervention().observe(getActivity(), intervention -> {
            if(intervention!= null && intervention.getArticles() != null)
                stockAdapter.putData(intervention.getArticles());
        });

        interventionViewModel.getExceptions().observe(getActivity(), exception ->{
            if(exception instanceof QuantityOverflowException){
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No you just can't add more stock than there is available!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            if(exception instanceof ScannedArticleNotFoundException){
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "This article doesn't even exist! Get your shit together please!²", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        return view;
    }


    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if(context instanceof INextStep){
            nextStep = (INextStep) context;
        }
        else{
            throw new  RuntimeException(context.toString() + " must implement INextStep");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        nextStep = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the Fragments code.

Comment: @SushobhNadiger I just updated the post accordingly

Comment: I think you shouldn't call getActivity in onCreate. It is possible that you view will be created befor your Activity is created. Try to do it later.

Answer (score 2):

I would remove this code

```
interventionViewModel.getExceptions().observe(this, exception ->{
        if(exception instanceof QuantityOverflowException){
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No you just can't add more stock than there is available!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        if(exception instanceof ScannedArticleNotFoundException){
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "This article doesn't even exist! Get your shit together please!²", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

and override the [onactivitycreated](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#onactivitycreated) method and put it there. You can then be sure that `getActivity()` will not return null. Note also that in the observe method i am passing the instance of the fragment and not the activity , so the obsever will respect the lifecycle of the fragment.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think this is going to work.. It does not matter where you attach the observer. What matters is that the fragment has to be attached when the model changes. If the model continues to change when the fragment has detached, then events should be ignored because there is no context at this point. So, moving the code to `onActivityCreated` most likely will not fix the problem..

Comment: I have updated the answer. Let me know if you think it will work.

Comment: That part I'm not sure, depends on the implementation of the observer which is not included in the question.. So the author will let you know :)

Comment: I did pass the reference to the fragment to my observer at the beginning but I had issues passing data accross fragment in my case. Using `getActivity()` was the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

Your code crashes because your "exceptions observer" ignores the fragment's lifecycle.

A fragment can be attached/detached from activity in many different scenarios such as configuration changes or moving the app to background, etc. When a fragment is detached, `getActivity()` method returns null, which is the reason of your crash.

On the other hand, the lifecycle of the object `interventionViewModel.getExceptions()` is completely independent. Every time the object changes, the observer gets called, not matter in what state the fragment is. So, if the fragment is detached, the app will crash.

To fix this problem - do not use context when the fragment is detached. Usually you don't want to listen to model changes when fragment detaches from activity. If you unregister the observer in `onDetach` it will fix your issue.

Good luck!

Comment: I tried it, but I can't tell if it worked or not since I don't know how to reproduce my bug

Comment: Is there a way to trigger the `interventionViewModel.getExceptions()` update when the app is in the background? That might be the way to test it. Another option to try is to rotate the device when `interventionViewModel.getExceptions()` is being updated. When you rotate the device the fragment also gets detached, so might also reproduce the bug.

Comment: The only way I can think of is by spamming the + and - buttons. I'll try to get a more reliable solution